# function value is returned as null

Tags: python, numpy, assert

I try to run this piece of code I get the dimension not same issue. Also when i try to print the values of Strikes and option_value_seqs, I get no return for "option_value_seqs"

```
import numpy as np
def bsm_mcs_valuation(strike):
    s0=100;T=1.0;r=0.05;vol=0.2;M=50;I=200
    dt=T/M
    rand= np.random.standard_normal((M+1,I))
    s=np.zeros((M+1,I));s[0]=100
    for t in range(1,M+1):
        s[t]= s[t-1]*np.exp((r - 0.5 * vol **2 ) * dt 
                        + vol *  np.sqrt(dt) * rand[t])

    value = (np.exp(-r*t)*np.sum(np.maximum(s[-1]-strike,0))/I)
    return value

def seq_value(n):
    strikes = np.linspace(80,120,n)
    print strikes
    option_values = []
    for strike in strikes:
        print strike
        print "option value is "; 
        option_values.append(bsm_mcs_valuation(strike))
    return strikes, option_values

n=100
%time strikes,option_values_seq=seq_value(n)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
plt.plot(strikes,option_values_seq,'b')
plt.plot(strikes,option_values_seq,'r')
```

***I get the following error***

```
221         y = _check_1d(y)
222         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
223             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")


ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

Comment: Could you fix your indentation, please?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. `s[t]` will be a float, so why are you asserting that it's equal to an empty string?

Comment: `assert` statement needs to return `True` in order to pass. In your example you are checking if `s[t] == ''` and because it's not, you are receiving `AssertionError`

Comment: Print your `strikes` and `option_values_seq` before plotting them. They need to have the same dimension and the same number of items.

Comment: @Nf4r, I have edited the issue above

Comment: @Nf4r-  I did try printing strikes and option_values_seq however option_values_seq was null '0.0'. That led me to think that issue is related to value and i tried tracing back using assert. However, I believe " bsm_mcs_valuation" function is returning null values.

Comment: Python doesn't have null values. `None` is not null nor is `0.0`

Comment: @ cricket_007 
Thanks, but I am struggling why i am getting dimension issue with above piece of code as both strikes (random generated) and relevant function (bsm_mcs_valuation) should return values of similar dimension.

Comment: its done... my silly mistake on indentation and wrong formula led to this disaster for 2 hours... thanks everyone for your help.